# protected base of class

Tags: c++, class, oop

In line 16, when i use `public` it works but when i try to use `protected` base type it gives me a compile error. Can someone explain me in brief please. 
I assume its because protected members of a base class are like a private members, but i am not sure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


// base class
class College
{
    //private:
protected:
    string name;
public:
    College(string name = "any college")
    { this->name = name; cout << "base College constructor\n"; }
    ~College() { cout << "base College destructor\n"; }
    string getName() const { return name; }
};

// derived class
class CommunityCollege : protected College //(public college it works)
{
private:
    string district;
public:
    CommunityCollege(string name, string district) : College(name)
    { this->district = district; cout << "derived Community College constructor\n"; }
    ~CommunityCollege() { cout << "derived Community College destructor\n"; }
    string getDistrict() const { return district; }
    void printName() const { cout << name << endl; }

};

class FHDA : public CommunityCollege
{
private:
    int numStudents;
public:
    FHDA(string name, string district, int num) : CommunityCollege (name, district)
    { this->numStudents = num; cout << "derived 2 FHDA constructor\n"; }
    ~FHDA() { cout << "derived 2 FHDA destructor\n"; }
    int getStudentNum() const { return numStudents; }
};

int main()
{

     /////////////////////// Part 1: inheritance basics //////////////////////

     CommunityCollege da ("foothill", "fhda");
     cout << da.getName() << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protected members acts like private for everything which doesn't is derived from that class, but when some other class inherits class with protected member it is accessible for it as public.

Answer (score 0):

This is called protected inheritance.
What it simply means, protected inheritance is **ONLY** visible to base class and it's children. From the outer world, no-one is able see whether CommunityCollege was derived from College.

If you wish to use some function from base class, you may use using declaration in the public declaration of the derived class:

```
using College::getName;
```

Answer (score -1):

compiling your example gives the error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:16:12: error: ‘std::string College::getName() const’ is inaccessible
     string getName() const { return name; }
            ^
main.cpp:50:25: error: within this context
      cout << da.getName() << endl;
                         ^
main.cpp:50:25: error: ‘College’ is not an accessible base of ‘CommunityCollege’
```

you are trying to call the member function getName() which is inherited from the base class. When you use protected inheritance, public functions from the base class will be protected in the child class (for more information see [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance-in-c)), so they are not accessible from outside.

I do not know of any use-case for protected inheritance, IMHO it just exists for completeness reasons.